# using Sessions in express-ws app and typescript

Tags: typescript, express, websocket

I am trying to build a node server with `express` and `express-ws` using Typescript.
I want to use Sessions in my app. So I have used `express-session`.

Below is pseudo code :

```
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as express from 'express'
import * as expressWs from 'express-ws'

const sessionParser = session({
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: '$eCuRiTy',
    resave: false
});

let expressWsApp = expressWs(expressApp, webServer, {
    wsOptions : {
        verifyClient : (info, done) => {
            sessionParser(info.req, {}, () => {
                done(info.req.session.userId);
            });
        }
    }
}).app
```

I am getting following error.

```
Argument of type 'IncomingMessage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Request' in 
sessionParser(info.req, {}, () => {...
```

Now problem is that, `sessionParser` requires 1st argument to be of type `express.Request`. And actually `express.Request` is child of `http.IncomingMessage`.

So How do I typecast parent class to child class ?

Any idea how to solve this ?
or how to use session with `express-session` in typescript

If I replace

```
 import * as session from 'express-session';
```

with

```
 const session = require('express-session');
```

It is working. But how to do it with `import` and type checking ?

Comment: You could install typings for this package. `npm i @types/express-session`

Comment: I have already added typings that's why issue is coming, without typing it won't give error.

Answer (score 0):

Just try doing this

```
let expressWsApp = expressWs(expressApp, webServer, {
    wsOptions : {
        verifyClient : (info, done) => {
            info.req.res = {}; 
            sessionParser(info.req, info.req.res, () => {
                done(info.req.session.userId);
            });
        }
    }
}).app
```